# How to declare a class function to reverse letter in the first word of a sentence

Tags: php, oop

I have already declared a function to revers whole sentence:

```
<?php
class String {

    private $error;
    private $length;
    private $string = "";
    private $array = array();
    private $index = 0;
    private $indexOf = false;

    private $word;
    private $str;


    public function __construct($string="") {
        $this->string = $string;

    }

    public function revers_sentence() {
        $this->string = strrev($this->string);
        return $this;
    }
```

... but how to declare a class function to revers letter in the first word of a sentence?

```
public function revers_1_word() {
    hmm ?
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you, or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function reverse_1_word() {
   $str_words = explode(" ", $this->string);
   $str_words[0] = strrev($str_words[0]);
   $this->string = implode(" ", $str_words);
   return $this;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd *declare* a method for this as follows:

```
public function reverse_first_word() {
    // Insert your implementation here.
}
```

:-)

Comment: @easyrider - No worries, I was just having a bit of fun. Incidentally, if you mark pjabang's answer as accepted (click on the grey tick to the left of his answer) both you and pjabang will receive reputation points. (The effective "currency" of Stack Overflow.)